# Add the empty space in the string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on the code to input the numbers in the string `self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER` when I'm pressing on the keyboard number buttons. I would like to add the empty string like this  in each time when I press on the keyboard number buttons.

```
DIGIT_BUTTONS = range(58, 68)

if action.getId() in DIGIT_BUTTONS:
    EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER = len(self.EPG_DIGIT)

    if EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER <= 2:
       self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER += str(action.getId() - 58)
    self.EPG_DIGIT += 1
    self.getControl(413).setLabel('[B]' + self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER + '[/B]')
```

When I press on the keyboard numbers 1,0,3, it will show `103` in the string. What I want to achieve is when I press on the keyboard number buttons 1,0,3, I want to make the string to show something is like: `1  0  3`. How I can do that?

Comment: You mean `'\t'.join(str(123))`

Comment: @Unni No what I mean is I have the string `103` I would like to make it get seperate which make it to show something is like `1   0   3`. How I can do that?

Comment: Is this what you mean `' '.join(list("103"))`?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 No, what I mean is when I press on the 1 button of the keyboard, the sting will show `1`, so I press on the 0 button of the keyboard to make it to show `10`. I want to make the space string which show `1   0` and when I press 3 button on the keyboard to make to show  `1   03` so I want to make the space to make it to show `1   0   3`. How I can do that??

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 it can be any number as the number are random.

Comment: Every time you add another number, add a space after it using the `+` operator

Comment: can you show me an example how I could do that when I am using `self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER += str(action.getId() - 58)` that will input the keyboard number buttons as I want to add a space after when I hit on the next two numbers?

Comment: `self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER += (str(action.getId() - 58)+' ')`, right?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, great, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER += str(action.getId() - 58)` to `self.EPG_DIGIT_NUMBER += (str(action.getId() - 58)+' ')` so that a space gets appended to the end of the number after each time a number is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `' '.join(str("your_string_here"))`

Comment: This is clearly not the answer, as shown in the comments.